# Calculating the area covered by at least one of three rectangles

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have a problem where I would need to calculate the area covered by at least one of three rectangles.

I've defined a function `calculate` as follows (apologies for the redundant variables it was for clarity):

```
def calculate(rec1, rec2, rec3):
    if rec1 == rec2 == rec3:
        return abs((rec1[1]-rec1[3])) * abs(rec1[0]-rec1[2])
    else:        
        area1 = abs((rec1[1]-rec1[3])) * abs(rec1[0]-rec1[2])
        area2 = abs((rec2[1]-rec2[3])) * abs(rec2[0]-rec2[2])
        area3 = abs((rec3[1]-rec3[3])) * abs(rec3[0]-rec3[2])
 
        xmin1, ymin1, xmax1, ymax1 = rec1[0], rec1[3], rec1[2], rec1[1]
        xmin2, ymin2, xmax2, ymax2 = rec2[0], rec2[3], rec2[2], rec2[1]
        xmin3, ymin3, xmax3, ymax3 = rec3[0], rec3[3], rec3[2], rec3[1]
 
        area12 = (min(xmax1, xmax2) - max(xmin1, xmin2)) * (min(ymax1, ymax2) - max(ymin1, ymin2))
        area13 = (min(xmax1, xmax3) - max(xmin1, xmin3)) * (min(ymax1, ymax3) - max(ymin1, ymin3))
        area23 = (min(xmax2, xmax3) - max(xmin2, xmin3)) * (min(ymax2, ymax3) - max(ymin2, ymin3))
        
        return (area1 + area2 + area3) - (area12 + area13 + area23)
```

However, this seems to be not working. What am I missing in the formula? `area12`, `area13` and `area23` are the areas of the intersecting triangles denoted by the last two digits in the end e.g `area12` is the area of intersection for `rec1` and `rec2`.

For the input ((x1, y1) denotes the left upper corner and (x2,y2) right lower corner)

```
(2,-1,3,-3),
(0,2,3,0),
(-3,0,1,-1)
```

I should get an output of `12`, but I get `13` and simply adding `+1` to the return value doesn't work in other test cases.

Comment: Are the inputs co ordinates

Comment: How is it you're creating rectangles from only 2 set of co ordinates.

Comment: @coderoftheday this might be of help (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/total-area-two-overlapping-rectangles/) it's a somewhat similar problem.

Comment: `simply adding +1 to the return value` is what I usually do to fix all my problems

Comment: Subtracting out the areas where two rectangles intersect, I've subtracted out the region where three rectangles intersect three times. So it would seem logical to add back to the sum by the inclusion-exclusion principle. @rioV8

Comment: is index of ymin==3 and index of ymax==1, use objects with field names

Comment: draw all possible cases of overlapping 3 rectangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the area of the union of the rectangles.

In the case of two rectangles, this area is the sum of the individual areas minus the area of the intersection. It is interesting to note that the intersection is also a rectangle (or empty). If we denote the intersection by `&` and the union by `|`, we have

```
Area(A | B) = Area(A) + Area(B) - Area(A & B).
```

To generalize to three rectangles, we can imagine that the above union is made of two positive rectangles and a negative one. Hence

```
Area(A | B | C) = Area((A | B) | C)
 = Area(A) + Area(C) - Area(A & C) + Area(B) + Area(C) - Area(B & C) - Area(A & B) - Area(C) + Area(A & B & C)
 = Area(A) + Area(B) + Area(C) - Area(B & C) - Area(C & A) - Area(A & B) + Area(A & B & C).
```

Then to find the area of the intersection of two rectangles it suffices to consider the rightmost of the two left sides and the leftmost of the two rights sides. If they are crossed, the intersection is empty. Otherwise their distance is the width of the intersection. A similar reasoning gives you the height.